# Как сделать, чтобы при изменении данных в одном словаре, во втором всё оставалось прежним?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Есть кусок кода:

```
import time


class Name:
    def __init__(self, settings: dict) -> None:
        self.settings = eval(str(settings))

    def update(self):
        self.settings["key"] = time.time()


settings = {"key":"value"}
SettingsClass = Name(settings)
print(id(settings) == id(SettingsClass.settings))  # 1 output
while id(settings) != id(SettingsClass.settings):
    SettingsClass.update()
    if SettingsClass.settings != settings:
        print('test') #2 output
        settings = SettingsClass.settings
```

Выполнение кода принесет:
False
test

Я где-то видел что, class принимая значения dict|list|tuple, берет только ссылку на переменную. А мне нужно чтобы это были 2 независимые переменные. Чтобы при изменении данных в одном словаре, во втором всё оставалось прежним до тех пор, пока не дойдет очередь до изменения. То есть: чтобы settings не изменялась вместе с SettingsClass.settings, пока не дойдет до кода settings = SettingsClass.settings (хотя именно из-за такого приравнивания, id становаятся одинаковыми и именно в этот момент копируется только ссылка на эту переменную).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть два варианта:

1. Использовать конструктор - подойдет, если у вас в словаре нет вложенных `dict | list | tuple`.

```
class Name:
    def __init__(self, settings: dict) -> None:
        self.settings = dict(settings)

    def update(self):
        self.settings["key"] = time.time()
```

2. Использовать `copy.deepcopy` - следует использовать, если есть вложенные `dict | list | tuple`

```
import copy

class Name:
    def __init__(self, settings: dict) -> None:
        self.settings = copy.deepcopy(settings)

    def update(self):
        self.settings["key"] = time.time()
```

Comment: О боже. Ошибка даже была не по теме этого вопроса..... Но ваш ответ идеально дал ответ на поставленный вопрос. Спасибо Вам за оперативность! Теперь будет номральный код, вместо костыля eval(str(dict())).... хахах. Если нужно более подробное описание ошибки, дайте знать. Хорошего дня!.